# Cannot write igraph object to file (forbidden control character error)

Tags: r, igraph

When trying to write an `igraph` object to file, I receive the following error:

`Error in .Call("R_igraph_write_graph_graphml", graph, file, as.logical(prefixAttr),  : 
  At foreign-graphml.c:1236 : Forbidden control character 0x08 found in igraph_i_xml_escape, Invalid value`

I am using the basic syntax for writing `igraph` objects to file in `graphml` format:

`write.graph(myGraphObject,"graph_object_to_file.graphml",format="graphml")`

I have tried converting all the character vector attributes of the graph to UTF-8 using the `iconv` function, however it has not worked so far.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the character attribute that contains a character with character code `0x08`, and fix it. That character stands for Backspace in the ASCII table, so I'm pretty sure that this is not meant to be there. Also, that character is disallowed in XML 1.0 anyway, so you won't be able to save it into an XML 1.0 file.

Converting to UTF-8 won't work because the UTF-8 equivalent of `0x08` is also `0x08`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have used `grep` but am unable to match a pattern for the character code `0x08`. Is there a special escape for this, or some kind of syntax?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with R, but you can probably use `charToRaw` to convert strings to ASCII codes, then look for any occurrence of the number 8 in the vector.

Comment: If you are only want to keep alphanumeric and punctuation characters, then you could try: `gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9,;._-]","",x)`, where `x` is any character vector that goes into the construction of your graph. For example, if you use `graph_from_dataframe` to construct the graph, then you `gsub` out the unwanted characters from the dataframe prior to running that function. Worked for me.